# controlar visibilidad de un botón

Tags: android

Quiero poner un ***botón invisible***, pero que este funcione todo el rato.
Lo quiero poner invisible porque quiero que se active pulsando una parte del `background` concreta.

El problema es que si uso `android:visibility="invisible"` o `"gone"` el botón no funciona

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:onClick="pge"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

este es el código xml del boton.

```
public void pge(View view){

    msToast("Hello");

}

public void msToast(String text){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

y esto es lo que uso para ver si funciona ( si el botón esta "visible" esto funciona así que esto no debería ser el problema)

Comment: Cuando usas android:visibility que error te muestra ?

Comment: No me sale ningún error, la aplicación se me ejecuta sin ningún problema, parece que cuando esta en "invisible" o "gone" el botón se deshabilite

Comment: el boton en estado gone, cumple la idea de no hacerle click, por algo lo ocultas, si quieres que el boton se muestre en determiandos momentos deberias realizar una tarea para que este este o no, ahora colocas este boton en invisible para que el usuario no le pueda dar click ?

Comment: la idea es que este siempre invisible pero se pueda hacer click en el, no quiero que se pueda ver el botón.

Comment: cuando uses android:visibility="gone" y llames al onClick que te mustra el log ?

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es sencillo, a la propiedad `android:background` del botón asignarle el valor `#00ff`. Eso le dará un color **transparente**.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:onClick="pge"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" 
    android:background="#00ff"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es exactamente lo que buscaba.